# The quickest way to change text font when browsing web?

Tags: browser, fonts, web, editing

I often want  to set the text on my screen to some of my favourite fonts (e.g. Candara, Century Gothic, ...). To do that I [use `inspect element` in the browser](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvhmxNH5DDc&ei=paSNUbaxG4O4rge1_ICQBw&usg=AFQjCNGt-Uv6s2nJWcA3aSzAZAI2X5NVwA&sig2=-vflXR3FB3GVGQiDGZC1hQ&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk) to change the css font of the element as in the snapshot.

This process is very tiring and time-consuming. What is the fastest way to change the font?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, try a Javascript Bookmarklet that updates the font perhaps.

Good guide here: http://daringfireball.net/2007/03/javascript_bookmarklet_builder

Comment: I'm not a javascript programmer to create my own font-changing bookmarklet. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the browser preferences. Most of the modern browsers allow you to override the website's fonts with your own settings.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain further.  I can't find this in the Firefox settings, unless you mean something like the Stylish addon, with a http://userstyles.org/ ?

Comment: Search for **Preferences** in the menu. Probably in the **Tools** (on Windows) or **Edit** (on Linux). Once you find that, click on the **Content** tab and in the **Font and Colors** section change the settings. Click on the **Advanced** button for more settings

Comment: I don't get this would help. Since the website specific some font for their own font intention in the css, how can a browser override that? E.g. in the css the font reads "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" and in the browser preferences it reads "standard, serif, sans-serif, fixed-width" - I tried to change the font and it doesn't work @Draxxxeus

Comment: If you click on the **Advanced** button, you will find a check box with the title **Allow pages to chose their own fonts, instead of my selections above**. You need to uncheck it (checked by default). Check this [image](http://imgur.com/XPDdhiw). If have changed the fonts for my browser using preferences.

Comment: This is to clear your doubt **Since the website specific some font for their own font intention in the css, how can a browser override that?**: When you load a page, the browser renders it. Even the fonts and css will be rendered by the browser. If the page is allowed to chose its own fonts, the browser will render it as it is else, it will render it with your settings.

Comment: Please give me a hint in Chrome browser for the Firefox option "Allow pages to chose their own fonts, instead of my selections above". Thank you @draxxxeus

Comment: On my Chrome browser the option is as this snapshot http://i.imgur.com/XIwr3XY.png

Comment: After reading [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68972) it looks like there is no way in chrome to override settings. The thread also mentions to check out the Chrome web Store for [accessibility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/22-accessibility) plugins.

Comment: The `accessibility` link leads to no extension @draxxxeus